# php compare arrays on separate keys

Tags: php

I have two arrays. The first array contains test scores, the second array is a set of conditions on how to handle the test scores, I need to cycle through each of the second array, in order, and test it to where the [scale] = the the matching key in the first array. I am using the value from the keys in the first array, so for example when:

```
[scale] => FVA
[operator] => >
[value] => 17
```

[scale] `FVA` would be compared against the value `2` of key [FVA] to test if it is greater than `>` 17, if it is not it goes to the next case in array #2.

This is in order to output a letter, so in sequence the results determine which text file is opened to make the body of the letter from [filename].

array #1 looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [sam] => 8 
    [fam] => 8 
    [cor] => 6 
    [rap] => 0 
    [sym] => 5 
    [oat] => 6 
    [sat] => 2 
    [def] => 6 
    [fva] => 2 
    [fvod] => 6 
)
```

array #2 looks something like this (abbreviated version):

```
Array ( 
    [Id] => 251 
    [table_name] => ADULT3CL 
    [test_type] => 1 
    [line_nbr] => 10 
    [scale] => 
    [operator] => 
    [value] => 0 
    [filename] => CAUTION.TX3 
    [goto_line] => 20 
    [report_nbr] => 0 
)
Array ( 
    [Id] => 252 
    [table_name] => ADULT3CL 
    [test_type] => 1 
    [line_nbr] => 20 
    [scale] => RAP 
    [operator] => > 
    [value] => 1 
    [filename] => RAP.TX3 
    [goto_line] => 30 
    [report_nbr] => 0 
)
Array ( 
    [Id] => 253 
    [table_name] => ADULT3CL 
    [test_type] => 1 
    [line_nbr] => 30 
    [scale] => FVA 
    [operator] => > 
    [value] => 17 
    [filename] => AND 
    [goto_line] => 0 
    [report_nbr] => 0 
)
```

My code so far, except I really have no idea where to go with this:

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$scoringtable_query =    "
          SELECT *
          FROM scoringtables
          WHERE test_type = ".$ttype."
          ORDER BY line_nbr
          ";
$db->setQuery($scoringtable_query);
$scoringtable = $db->loadAssocList();
echo'<p>'.print_r($sassi_result).'</p>';
foreach($scoringtable as $case):
    echo'<p>'.print_r($case).'</p>';
    /*if(empty($case[scale])):
        echo '<p>'.file_get_contents('v_sassi/'.$case[filename], FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH).'</p>';

    endif;*/
endforeach;
```

Comment: So you're not actually using the number value from array #1?

Comment: I am using the value from the keys in the first array, so for example when [scale] => FVA [operator] => > [value] => 17, it would be compared against the value of key FVA to test if it is greater than 17, if it is not it goes to the next case in array #2

Comment: Wow, OK.  You probably should put that as well as other info in the question.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($arr2 AS $result){
  $key = strtolower($result['scale']);
  if(isset($arr1[$key])){
     //Do stuff here.
  }
}
```

I can't tell from your sample code which array is what variable.

Comment: the first array is from something earlier in my code $sassi_result and the 2ns array example is the result of the foreach loop of $scoringtable as $case

Answer (score 0):

From your comments it's a little more involved.  You didn't mention `<` or `=` or other operator.  Also, no mention if certain things don't exist, such as operator or value, or scale in either array.

```
foreach($array2 as $case) {
    $scale = strtolower($case['scale']);
    $op = $case['operator'];
    $value = $case['value'];

    if(isset($array1[$scale]) && !empty($op)) {
        switch($op) {
            case '>':
                $file = ($array1[$scale] > $value) ? $case['filename'] : null;
                break;
            case '<':
                $file = ($array1[$scale] < $value) ? $case['filename'] : null;
                break;
        }
        if(isset($file) && file_exists('v_sassi/' . $file)) {
            echo '<p>' . file_get_contents('v_sassi/' . $file) . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: we are on the right path, there are instances where a scale doesnt exist. i think the reason this isnt working is that $scale is outputting as:

rapfvafvodsexfvafvodsexfvasexfvasexfvodsexfvodsexsymoatsatoatsatfvafvodsamoatdefsamfvafvodsatdefsamsexfvafvodsatdefsamsexsymoatsatsexsymoatsatsexdefsamfvafvoddefsatoatsatoatsexoatsexfvafvodoatdefsamsamsamsamfvafvodoatsatsexoatsatsexdefsamcorfamsexfamsexfamsexfvafvodoatsatdeffvafvodoatsatdef

Comment: now that i look an an entire array of $case there are instances where operator and/or scale do not exist.